# Accompanying my vaccinated Indonesian girlfriend for a 3 week visit of Indonesia as unvaccinated person

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, bali

In mid June my girlfriend (Indonesian and 3 times Covid vaccinated) and me (german and unvaccinated against Covid), will visit Indonesia for 15 days. Our first station in Indonesia is Bali (DPS).

What will happen at arrival in Bali to me and is there any preparation except getting vaccinated?

Official information is a bit inconsistent and I am more interested in the most probable practical handling than in political statements I can refer to.

Comment: I entered Indonesia in Jakarta in early February and they indeed checked vaccination documentation. I re-entered 3 weeks later in Bali, and no one checked anything. Of course, that's not a predictor of future performance.

Comment: you have time to get vaccinated by then, but it's a bit short, so don't waste time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I, the future self of the question asker, entered Indonesia in Mid June through Bali, nobody wanted to check anything about Covid. Same with domestic flight and bus travel. Also their Covid app Satusehat wasn't needed anywhere.

Same when leaving Indonesia some days ago.

Despite Indonesia still having official Covid restrictions at this time, in reality Covid things looked like remnants of a forgotten civilization, for example a Covid documents checking area was converted to a place with canvas chairs.

Answer (score 7):

Are you not vaccinated because of a medical condition or because you simply refuse the vaccination? In the first case, bring a certificate (translated into english) that certifies the reason why you did not get vaccinated.

If you just did not want to get the vaccine: stay at home. Indonesia still requires proof of vaccination. You might be lucky and get in, but you might as well not be. I entered Indonesia twice in November and  December and my certificate was checked both times. I also had to show proof of vaccination once when entering an airport before taking a domestic flight.
You made a conscious decision not to get vaccinated. Either bear the consequences or get vaccinated.

Answer (score 5):

TIMATIC (document database used by airlines) states :

> Passengers must have a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that
> they were fully vaccinated at least 14 days before departure. The
> certificate must be issued in both English and a local language of the
> country where passengers were vaccinated.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers younger than 18 years.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a COVID-19 recovery certificate stating that they are no longer contagious with COVID-19.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a letter issued by a doctor proving that the passenger is medically unable to receive the vaccine.
>
> Passengers must download the 'SatuSehat' mobile app before departure.
>
> Passengers and airline crew must complete the “electronic Customs
> Declaration (eCD)" at https://ecd.beacukai.go.id/ . This will generate
> a QR code which must be presented upon arrival.
>
> Passengers could be subject to a COVID-19 PCR test upon arrival.

About what counts as being fully vaccinated, the [US Embassy in Indonesia](https://id.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/covid-19-information/) state :

> #### Vaccination
>
> Travelers must show a physical or digital vaccination certificate for
> the second dose of COVID-19 vaccine received not less than 14 days
> prior to departure. This requirement does not apply to travelers under
> 18 years old; travelers who have special health conditions or
> comorbidities preventing vaccination (as demonstrated via letter from
> a medical doctor); travelers who have finished quarantine or recently
> recovered from COVID-19 (as demonstrated by a letter of recovery from
> a hospital or licensed doctor); or those travelers who have not been
> vaccinated but must travel domestically to depart via an international
> flight.
>
> The Indonesian Government recognizes the following vaccinations:
> two-doses Pfizer, Moderna, Sinovac, AstraZeneca, or Sinopharm and
> single-dose of Johnson & Johnson.
>
> #### Testing
>
> Upon arrival, travelers will complete a COVID-19 symptom check, and
> temperature check. If the traveler has no symptoms and normal If the
> traveler is symptomatic or has a body temperature above 99.5 F, a PCR
> test will be taken at the airport. If this test is positive, the
> traveler must isolate at their residence or a facility approved for
> COVID-19 isolation. The traveler is responsible for all associated
> costs.
>
> #### Quarantine
>
> - There is no quarantine requirement for travelers who are fully- vaccinated.
> - Quarantine period of 5 x 24 hours is needed for international travelers who have not been vaccinated or have received first dose of
>   vaccination of a two-dose vaccination regime.
> - Travelers under 18 years of age will follow the quarantine provisions of their parents/caregivers.
> - International travelers are responsible for all expenses during the quarantine, including the COVID-19/PCR tests

I'd make very sure that you'll have enough time to get vaccinated and leave 14 days out before leaving for Indonesia

Comment: Of course, with the WHO officially declaring the pandemic to be over we can expect all leftover Covid rules to be rapidly abandoned this summer.

Comment: @JonathanReez:  abandoning rules is often a slow process.  There is often less pressure to make a decision, so no decision gets made.

Comment: "Quarantine period of 5 x 24 hours is needed for international travelers who have not been vaccinated ..." Does that mean they can make the trip unvaccinated knowing they'll be subject to a 5-day quarantine period upon arrival?

Comment: @KevinFegan I think the quarantine period probably applies to the list of people/situations where "[t]his requirement does not apply..." in the **Vaccination** section.

Comment: @JonathanReez Governments should use this "declaring to be over" technique more often. They could simply declare that climate change is a hoax and Russia is not bombing Ukraine. Seems easier than actually changing things.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [latest Timatic update](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php), Indonesia dropped all Covid restrictions on June 9th 2023, meaning that anyone can enter the country without a vaccination certificate. Masks and all other restrictions have likewise been fully eliminated.